# Optimum way to load native shared library in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, singleton, shared-libraries

A work collegue has implemented a class to load native C++ shared libraries into our Android app, he named this class 'LibLoader'. His proposed solution was to instantiate a LibLoader object every time we needed to use one of the native functions declared in the native library. I believe this is not optimum from a performance point of view so I was thinking about the best way to optimize this.

So far two solutions have come into my mind:

1. Make the LibLoader class a singleton
2. Turn the native methods into static ones so I won't even have to make an object

Considering native shared libraries are loaded through static/instace initializacion in the class, my questions are:

1. Which of these two approaches would be the best from a performance point of view? I need my code to be fast, I'm calling these native functions several times to compute FFTs on real time audio samples
2. Is there another optimum way to do this?
3. What happens to static/instance initialization if the native methods are converted to static ones? Will it be called every time a static method is accessed?

My code is:

```
public class LibLoader {

static final String TAG = "LibLoader";
static boolean armv7 ;


static
{

    String arch = System.getProperty("os.arch");

    //determine which library to load according to CPU type
    if(arch.contentEquals("armv7l"))
    {
        //fftw neon compiled library functions work with armv71 and armv6
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("fftwfNeon_fftTwiddle"); //this won't load from any other platform
            armv7 = true;
        }catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load fftwfNeon_fftTwiddle library "+ e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    else
    {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("fftTwiddle");
            armv7 = false;
        }catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load fftTwiddle library "+ e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

public native void GetComplexFFtDoubleIN(double[] realIN, double[] imagIN, int fftSize, double[] TW, boolean ifftFlag);

public native void FFTWfNeonSymb(int fftSize, float[] realPart, float[] imagPart, boolean isFFT);

public native void FFTWfNeonSync(int fftSize, float[] realPart, float[] imagPart, boolean isFFT);
```

}

Comment: _"What happens to static/instance initialization if the native methods are converted to static ones? Will it be called every time a static method is accessed?"_ That would be very easy for you to test.

Answer (score 0):

Having your methods static vs creating an instance variable for the class, does not affect CPU performance much. But these 2 implementations differs a lot in memory usage.

If it is only FFT calculations then, I would suggest to keep it static. This can keep you code free from memory leaks.

Update: Creating a singleton is between the 2 options I have explained. Here are the 3 ways you can do it in the order of memory simplicity.

1. All methods are static and you directly access the methods from any class you want. (Only has the class in memory)
2. Having a singleton variable. Creating a new variable will always return the same static variable. (Keeps the class and the static    variable in memory)
3. Creating a new variable and deleting the memory after using the required methods in the class. (Allocates memory when needed and clears it when not in use.)

Comment: By "creating an instance variable for the class" do you mean making my class a singleton one? Would you mind explaining your answer?